# C++ | Trigger compilation error when return pointer type is different from actual pointer type

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I've got this class, called "Bundle", which acts as a transfer object between my business logic. By having two maps, one for const and one for non const values, I am able to preserve const-ness of data.

```
#pragma once
#include <lang/System.h>
#include <unordered_map>

class Bundle final : public Object {

private:

    std::unordered_map<int, void *> nonConstMap;
    std::unordered_map<int, const void *> constMap;

public:

    CLASS_NAME("util.Bundle")

    template <typename T, ENABLE_IF(IS_CONST(T))>
    void setData(const int& key, T& value) {

        constMap.emplace(key, &value);
    }

    template <typename T, ENABLE_IF(!IS_CONST(T))>
    void setData(const int& key, T& value) {

        nonConstMap.emplace(key, &value);
    }

    template <typename T,ENABLE_IF(!IS_CONST(T))>
    T* getData(const int& key) {
        
        return nonConstMap.count(key) > 0 ? static_cast<T*>(nonConstMap.at(key)) : null;
    }

    template <typename T, ENABLE_IF(IS_CONST(T))>
    const T* getData(const int& key) const {

        return constMap.count(key) > 0 ? static_cast<const T*>(constMap.at(key)) : null;
    }
};
```

Which works in this way:

```
class Main : public CppApplication {

public:
    
    CLASS_NAME("src.Main");

    virtual int main(const std::vector<String>& arguments) override {

        using StringReference = std::reference_wrapper<String>;
        Bundle myBundle;

        int intValue = 1;
        String stringValue= "2";
        String otherStringValue = "3";
        std::vector<StringReference> vectorValue = { otherStringValue };

        myBundle.setData<int>(1, intValue);
        myBundle.setData<String>(2, stringValue);
        myBundle.setData<std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<String>>>(3, vectorValue);
        
        std::cout << *myBundle.getData<int>(1) << std::endl;
        std::cout << *myBundle.getData<String>(2) << std::endl;
        std:: cout << (*myBundle.getData<std::vector<StringReference>>(3))[0].get() << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
};
SET_ENTRY_POINT(new Main());
```

It may happen in the future that one can invoke the "getData" method using a wrong template parameter type (i.e `getData<int>` instead of `getData<String>`). How can i trigger a compilation error when this happens?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by saying "erasing the type of the object held in the collection"? Are you referring to the fact that everything becomes a pointer to void*/const void*? Furthermore, std::variant seems to belong to c++17 and I'm compiling with c++14

Comment: Can you explain how you can expect to produce a compilation error if your C++ source consists of many different files and, for example, in `apple.cpp` you put an `int` in your map, and in `orange.cpp` your code attempts to get a `std::string` out from the same key? How do you expect your compiler to know, when compiling `orange.cpp`, that this particular key should be an `int`, instead of a `std::string`?

Comment: I was hoping to use SFINAE before returning the map value, but I don't think there is a way to say "ok check if this type is the same as the returned". I tried to use is_same type_traits but it's not working and I think it's because it is resolving the type contained in the map to void*/const void* and cannot go deeper. If that's the case then I just have to give up, or maybe there is another approach to solve my transfer object issue? This class was created in order to have heterogeneous data contained in one "container" without using a common superclass.

Comment: Maybe `std::any` and checking the result of `any_cast`?

Comment: You can't get a compile error here.  You could get a runtime error (rather than undefined behavior) if you use `std::any` instead of `void*` though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm studying the use of std::any. Unfortunately it is a c++17 feature, but is good to know this kind of stuff is already available in the newer version.

Comment: If you're using an older revision of C++ (and you're OK with pulling in Boost and all that entails) you could use `boost::any`.  `std::any`'s interface is based off the Boost version, so it's basically a drop-in replacement.

Comment: The reason that `is_same`, and similar will not work for you is because these are all ***compile time*** traits, and you need to implement this check at ***run time***. Unfortunately, C++ does not work this way, `is_same` cannot be used as a runtime check.